# Understanding the Relationship Between Monomorphisms and Short Exact Sequences in Abelian Categories

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I'm a beginner in category theory and currently learning about the kernel and the image of a morphism. I'm struggling to prove why, in an abelian category, a monomorphism $f: A \to B$ fits into the short exact sequence (SES):

$0 \to A \to B \to coker(f) \to 0$
when $f$ is the morphism between $A$ and $B$.

If I understood correctly, for a SES, we need $im(f) = ker(g)$. And I know that by definition $im(f) = ker(coker(f))$.

1. Firstly, why is $im(0) = ker(f)$? I know that $im(0) = ker(coker(0))$, but why does it make it equal to the kernel of $f$?
2. In the second stage, is it right to say that "by definition" of $im(f) = ker(coker(f))$ we get the equality? If so, where did we use the fact that $f$ is monic?
3. Similarly to the first stage, why is $im(coker(f)) = ker(0)$?

I tried proving all of the above using diagrams and the fact that $(co)kernel$ is the $(co)equalizer$ of the correct diagrams, but it didn't help me understand still. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(2)$: yes, this is true by definition. For $(1)$ and $(3)$ observe that a kernel for $X\overset{0}{\to}Y$ is just an isomorphism $Z\cong X$, and a cokernel is just an isomorphism $Z\cong Y$. For *every* map into $X$ has $0f=0$, including $1_X$, so $1_X$ must factor through the kernel and clearly that implies the kernel is an isomorphism (and it's easy to directly check $1_X:X\to X$ is a kernel) and you can argue similarly for the cokernel.

Thus, exactness of $0\to A\to B$ is exactly the same as saying $\ker f$ is a kernel for $1_A:A\to A$, and $\ker(1_A)$ must be a zero map (exercise) so it's the same as saying $\ker f$ is a zero map, so that $f$ is monic. I leave $(3)$ as a very similar exercise.

Comment: Thank you so much! that make a lot of sense.
but in an other case, where f is epimorphism, how can we justify the second equality in the SES $0 \to ker(g) \to A \to B \to 0$? Because in this case the second equality is not simply proves by the definition of the image. thanks!

Comment: @yoyok3 In any Abelian category, $\ker\operatorname{coker}\ker=\ker$ holds, so the image morphism for $\ker g$ is just $\ker g$ itself

Comment: thanks! also, is there a way to prove that if f is a monic, so its kernel is a zero morphism? as i see the definition of a monic, its just point that if $fg=fg'$ so $g=g'$. But how can i understand from this definition that the kernel is indeed a zero map?

Comment: @yoyok3 Well, $fg=0=f0$ iff. $g=0$, if $f$ is monic, so you can check $0$ has the universal kernel property